# UI pink on Android device

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a simple default button with text, it looks fine on Unity, but when I build it on my Android phone, I get a pink line instead of a button and no text on it. My button doesn't have any shaders (it's a default button without any changes on it besides a function).

I have no idea what causes it, it probably has something to do with shaders, but I don't use any.

Unity version: 5.5.2f1

Android: 6.0.1

Comment: Don't you think it would  be useful to post your Unity and Android version since this looks more like a bug?

Comment: You are right. Added

Comment: Does this affect all the Buttons or just one? Delete your current Button then create a new one and see what happens.

Comment: All buttons. No it doesn't help to delete

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug but and are possible workaround:

**1**.The UI is likely missing its default shader. Re-add it from the Editor.

Go to Edit ---> Project Settings ---> Graphics ---> Built-in shader settings.

Change the *Size* to **7** then add each shader in there. Below is an image of what that should look like:

[image]

**2**.Disable 32-Bit Display Buffer

You can do that by going to

*File* ---> *Build Settings*, select *Android* then go to *Player Settings* ---> *Resolution and Presentation* 
then un-check the *"Use 32-Bit Display Buffer"* checkbox.

[image]

If this solves the problem, update Unity to the latest version (5.6) then go back to this settings and enable it back.

**3**.The Max Size of the Texture you use for the Button is too big. Reduce it to about *1024* or less. Most of the times there is no problem with *2048* but don't let the size be more than this on Android.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I added the UI/Default shader and it solved the problem!

Comment: Nice. The shader was not present on the device since it's not added. Happy coding!